# Camunda 7 External Client with HTTPS having SSL exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, camunda

I have created a external client in a spring boot project. I have following properties set

```
camunda:
  bpm:
    client:
      base-url:https://server/engine-rest

server:
  ssl:
   
    trust-store: classpath:keystore/truststore.jks
    key-store: classpath:keystore/keystore.jks
    enabled: true
    key-store-password: pp
    trust-store-password: pp
    keyStoreType: JKS
  port: '8080'
```

But I am getting following error

```
org.camunda.bpm.client.impl.EngineClientException: TASK/CLIENT-02002 Exception while establishing connection for request 'POST /engine-rest/external-task/fetchAndLock HTTP/1.1' 
at org.camunda.bpm.client.impl.EngineClientLogger.exceptionWhileEstablishingConnection(EngineClientLogger.java:36) ~[camunda-external-task-client-7.15.0-alpha5.jar:7.15.0-alpha5]

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```